# ID guardado correctamente pero devuelve 0

Tags: java

Tengo una duda quería saber qué devolvería el `returnz`, por que quería que el metodo devolviese la ID del CD insertado pero no lo hace y no lo acabo de comprender.

La ID se genera automáticamente en la base de datos y mi problema es que si pido la id me sale que es 0 , pero luego se guarda bien en la base de datos. No lo entiendo, ¿por qué ocurre eso?

Éste es mi código:

```
public int insertCd(Cd cd) {
    Integer returnz = null;        
    try {
        iniciaOperacion();//
        //tx = session.beginTransaction();
        returnz = (Integer) session.save(cd);
        tx.commit();        
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        if (tx != null)//
            tx.rollback();
        System.out.println("Problem creating session factory");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return returnz;
}

private void iniciaOperacion() throws HibernateException {
    session = HibernateDAO.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();    
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cd")

public class Cd {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id; //Id of the cd

    @Column(name ="titol")
    private String titol;

    @Column(name="autor")
    private String autor;

    @Column(name="any")
    private int any;

    public  Cd(){}


    public Cd(int id, String titol, String autor, int any) {
        this.id = id;
        this.titol = titol;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.any = any;
    }
```

Comment: Intenta tabular y usar las etiquetas de código.

Comment: Perdon soy nuevo...gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué problema/error te sale?¿Qué es lo que te hace este código exactamente?

Comment: Deberías poner también iniciaOperacion() dado que puede ser un error al obtener el session o iniciar la transacción.

Comment: Cuelga tu objeto de tipo Cd

Comment: ¿El id se genera de manera automática en la BD? ¿Cómo está definida la tabla?

Comment: Correcto se genera automaticamente!

Comment: Prueba a añadir @GeneratedValue al campo id

Comment: Osea mi problema es que si pido la id se me sale que la id es 0 , pero luego se guarda bien en la base de datos...no lo entiendo.

Comment: Puede ser que Hibernate no esté haciendo la insert de manera immediata y por eso no tengas el id en ese momento. Haz un session.flush() para forzar la inserción.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar:  `returnz = (Integer) session.save(cd);` por esto: **`session.save(cd); returnz = cd.getId();`** Es decir, aplica el método `getId()` del objeto **después de haberlo guardado**.